# Solution for CSS Border iOS appearance issue?

Tags: css, css-selectors, border, text-decorations, text-styling

I recently added the following code to one of my text elements to add a cool underline to it:

```
border-bottom: 2px solid transparent!important;
border-image: linear-gradient(0.25turn, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 204, 0));
border-image-slice: 1;
width: fit-content!important;
```

It looks like this on chrome and Android:
[live picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBquS.png)

However, on iOS devices the border completely surrounds the whole text and looks like this:
[iOS live picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilMPT.png)

I tried some -webkit and -moz-fit-content type of things but since I am not actively in programming I did not get it to work.

I hope someone can help with this problem and I appreciate your solutions!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your border-image-slice, give it precision and it will be ok :)
I've tested it and it works on Safari v 13.1.2

Aurélie

```css
p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent!important;
border-image: linear-gradient(0.25turn, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 204, 0));
border-image-slice: 0 0 1 0;
width: fit-content!important;
}
```

```html
<p>Biscuit cake sweet roll. Carrot cake caramels</p>
```